# Python asyncio: reader callback and coroutine communication

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, coroutine, python-asyncio

I am trying to implement a simple idea of passing a data from stdin to a coroutine:

```
import asyncio
import sys

event = asyncio.Event()

def handle_stdin():
    data = sys.stdin.readline()
    event.data = data  # NOTE: data assigned to the event object
    event.set()

@asyncio.coroutine
def tick():
    while 1:
        print('Tick')
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

        if event.is_set():
            data = event.data  # NOTE: data read from the event object
            print('Data received: {}'.format(data))
            event.clear()

def main(): 
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.add_reader(sys.stdin, handle_stdin)
    loop.run_until_complete(tick())    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code works fine, however a simplified version of it with a variable instead of an `Event` object works too:

```
data = None

def handle_stdin():
    global data
    data = sys.stdin.readline()

@asyncio.coroutine
def tick():
    while 1:
        print('Tick')
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

        global data
        if data is not None:
            print('Data received: {}'.format(data))
            data = None
```

My questions are: is the approach with `Event` correct? Or is there a better way with another asyncio objects to handle this kind of problem? 
Then, if the approach with `Event` is fine, is using a variable is fine as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue) is much better suited for this kind of producer/consumer relationship:

```
import asyncio
import sys

queue = asyncio.Queue()

def handle_stdin():
    data = sys.stdin.readline()
    # Queue.put is a coroutine, so you can't call it directly.
    asyncio.create_task(queue.put(data)) 
    # Alternatively, Queue.put_nowait() is not a coroutine, so it can be called directly.
    # queue.put_nowait(data)

async def tick():
    while 1:
        data = await queue.get()
        print('Data received: {}'.format(data))

def main(): 
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.add_reader(sys.stdin, handle_stdin)
    loop.run_until_complete(tick())    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There's less logic involved than with an `Event`, which you need to make sure you set/unset properly, and there's no need for a `sleep`, wakeup, check, go back to sleep, loop, like with the global variable. So the the `Queue` approach is simpler, smaller, and blocks the event loop less than your other possible solutions. The other solutions are technically *correct*, in that they will function properly (as long as you don't introduce any `yield from` calls inside if `if event.is_set()` and `if data is not None:` blocks). They're just a bit clunky.

Comment: Thank you very much @dano, `queue` approach looks indeed better than the `"event"` one.

Comment: Is that `asyncio.async` correct? Gives me a syntax error

Comment: @Osman-pasha It was at the time I wrote the naswer, but it has since been deprecated and removed. I updated my answer to use the method that should be called instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait for an event, you should probably be using [`Event.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event.wait) instead of polling `is_set`.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def tick():
    while True:
        yield from event.wait()
        print('Data received: {}'.format(event.data))
        event.clear()
```

Comment: True, in fact even a simple `yield from event.wait()` without a loop should be sufficient.