# Python - asyncio - Wait for a future inside a callback

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

Here is my code, I want `my_reader` to wait maximum 5 seconds for a future then do something with the `my_future.result()`. Please note that `my_reader` is **not** a **coroutine**, it is a **callback**.

```
import asyncio, socket

sock = ...

async def my_coroutine():
    ...

def my_reader():
    my_future = asyncio.Future()
    ...

    # I want to wait (with a timeout) for my_future


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.add_reader(sock, my_reader)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

I don't want to use either:

- `AbstractEventLoop.create_datagram_endpoint()`
- `AbstractEventLoop.create_connection()`
- ...

The socket I have is returned from another module and I have to read packets with a given size. The transfer must happen under 5 seconds.

**How to wait for a future inside a callback?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, waiting in **callbacks** is impossible.
Callback should be executed instantly by definition -- otherwise event loop hangs on callback execution period.

Your logic should be built on **coroutines** but low-level *on_read* callback may inform these coroutines by setting a value of future.

See [aiopg.connection](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg/blob/master/aiopg/connection.py) for inspiration. The callback is named `Connection._ready`.

Comment: It's very low level API (like `asyncio.Protocol` BTW).
Coroutines operate on higher levels.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the coroutine separately and send data to it from the callback via Queue.

Look on this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29475218/1112457